# Pybullet - Parallelogram joints aren’t allowed

Tags: python, python-3.x, simulation, physics, pybullet

I have a custom robot URDF that I imported which has parallelogram limbs. The only way I could get it to import was by only creating 3 of the 4 joints on the polygon, and “forcing” all those joints to line up by setting all their angles to the same value. However, the robot isn’t as strong that way, and it doesn’t quite line up if there’s an external force.

I tried using the `createConstraint` function but that caused my robot to fly off the screen... *shrug*

I feel like there should be a simple way to do this, but I couldn’t find a solution after hours of googling.

Many thanks in advance!